# Java Regular expression with variable string

Tags: java, regex

I want to find the occurrences of all the words in a ListArray comparing it with a String. So far, I am able to do it as a for loop, where I store all the possible combinations and run them using a matches i.e.

```
        for(String temp_keywords: keywords){
        final_keywords_list.add(" "+ temp_keywords+ " ");
        final_keywords_list.add(" "+ temp_keywords+".");
        final_keywords_list.add(" "+ temp_keywords+ ",");
        final_keywords_list.add(" "+ temp_keywords+ "!");
        final_keywords_list.add(" "+ temp_keywords+ "/");
        final_keywords_list.add(" "+ temp_keywords+ "?");
    }
    for (String temp_keywords : final_keywords_list) {
            String add_space = temp_keywords.toLowerCase();
            p = Pattern.compile(add_space);
            m = p.matcher(handler_string);
            int count = 0;
            while (m.find()) {
                count += 1;
            }
```

However, I want to remove the manual addition for the combinations and do a regex. I've seen examples of words with regex but how do I add a variable string to the regex? Sorry, I am a beginner java learner.

Comment: you aren't using final_keywords_list in your code. Are you supposed to match values with temp_keywords or with final_keywords_list?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I will have to do that. Sorry, this is a part of a large code. I'll edit it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
String inputString = ....
String[] keywords = ....

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(String keyword: keywords)
  sb.append("(?<= )").append(keyword).append("(?=[ .,!/?])").append("|");
sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1); //Removes trailing "|". Assumes keywords.size() > 0.

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(sb.toString());
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);
int count = 0;
while (m.find())
  count++;
```

It creates a single regex, compiles it, and then counts the matches.

Comment: Thank you! StringBuilder is what I was looking for! I was simply trying to concat the strings and the regex part and it obviously didn't work. I shall read up on StringBuilder.

Comment: Sorry, spaces between words of keywords? As in, if the keyword was 'bread and'?

Comment: @PR: Before my fix, it didn't count correctly " hello world " as 2. Now I'm using positive lookahead/lookbehind, so it works fine.

Comment: Please note that when the input string terminates with one of your words it will also fail to count it, but that's also true with your original solution so I assumed you don't need it.

Comment: Awesome. I didn't think of that drawback! And true, I don't need it for my code. Thank you.